# Form fields duplicating when using nested fields via simple_fields_for in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a form that needs to allow a user to specify pricing for multiple combinations of locations and price types that relate back to a kit.

Think about it like "This kit costs $X at location Y for the type of Z."

The desired layout is to have things laid out such that the page reads:

**Location A**

- Price Type 1's Price Field
- Price Type 2's Price Field

**Location B**

- Price Type 1's Price Field
- Price Type 2's Price Field

**Location C**

- Price Type 1's Price Field
- Price Type 2's Price Field

To accomplish this, I have the following in my `_form.html.erb` view:

```
<h2>Pricing</h2>
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <h2><%= location.name %></h2>
  <div>
    <% @price_types.each do |price_type| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :kit_pricings do |p| %>
        <% if f.object.new_record? %>
          <%= p.input :location_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => location.id } %>
          <%= p.input :price_type_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => price_type.id } %>
        <% end %>
        <%= p.input :price, :label => price_type.name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This iterates over each location, then each price type within that and produces a form field for each. This works perfectly upon creating a new kit.

However, when you go to edit a kit, which uses the same view partial, all hell breaks loose.

As best I can discern, for each occurrence of `<%= p.input :price, :label => price_type.name %>`, **all** items that match the `kit_id` of the current kit being edited. This results in a ton of duplicated form fields on the page.

The most interesting part is that if you edit and save it, it works correctly so long as you edit the last set of fields on the page.

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something at this point.

In case it's helpful, this is what my controller has inside:

```
  def new
    @kit = Kit.new
    @kit.kit_pricings.build
    @locations = Location.all
    @price_types = PriceType.all
  end

  def edit
    @locations = Location.all
    @price_types = PriceType.all
  end
```

**Kit Model**

```
class Kit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kit_pricings
  has_many :locations, through: :kit_pricings
  has_many :price_types, through: :kit_pricings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kit_pricings, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Kit Pricings Model**

```
class KitPricing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kit
  has_one :locations
  has_one :pricing_types
end
```

**Locations Model**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kit_pricing
end
```

**Price Type Model**

```
class PriceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kit_pricing
end
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the model relationships ?

Comment: Sure thing @ArupRakshit. I added the models involved to the post above.